# Not able to link verilog modules

Tags: verilog

I have tried to code an address generation unit. The code is as follows:

```
module access3x3(clk, addr, dout);

input clk;
output [16:0] addr;
output [7:0] dout;

reg [16:0] addr;

reg clk1;
wire [3:0] count;

wire [16:0] addr_reg [2:0];

wire val;
wire [7:0] val1;

assign val=0;
assign val1=0;
assign addr_reg[0]=0;

initial
begin
    addr=0;
    clk1=1;
end

inputhex image(.clka(clk), .wea(val), .addra(addr), .dina(val1), 
.douta(dout));
counter1 count64516(.clk(clk1), .dout(addr_reg[0]));
counter9 count9(.clk(clk), .dout(count));
adder256 row2(.din(addr_reg[0]), .dout(addr_reg[1]), .clk(clk));
adder256 row3(.din(addr_reg[1]), .dout(addr_reg[2]), .clk(clk));

always@(negedge clk)
begin

case(count)
0: addr=(addr_reg[0]+1'b0); 
1: addr=(addr_reg[0]+2'd1);
2: addr=(addr_reg[0]+2'd2);
3: addr=(addr_reg[1]+1'b0);
4: addr=(addr_reg[1]+2'd1);
5: addr=(addr_reg[1]+2'd2);
6: addr=(addr_reg[2]+1'b0);
7: addr=(addr_reg[2]+2'd1);
8: addr=(addr_reg[2]+2'd2);
endcase


if(count==4'd4)
    clk1=0;
else if(count==4'd8)
    clk1=1;
end
endmodule
```

This is the updated top level code. The Counter1 code is as follows:

```
module counter1(clk, dout);

input clk;
output [16:0] dout;
reg [16:0] dout;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(dout<17'd64516)
    dout=(dout+17'd1);
else
    dout=17'b0;
end


endmodule
```

The issue is that when the output of dout from counter1 changes from 00000000000000000 to 00000000000000001, the value of addr_reg[0] changes from 00000000000000000 to 0000000000000000X. What can be the issue?

Comment: `addr_reg` should be a `wire`, not a `reg`, as it is connected to `.dout`s. `clk1` should have an initial value.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It worked. addr_reg was supposed to be a wire. Initialised clk1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when some signals are output it should be declared as `wire`.

```
wire [7:0] dout;
wire [3:0] count;
```

The second thing is `dout_reg[count]=dout` how do you assign `output` to internal signal? I think here also could be an error. Check the logic. 
 And will be clearer(where are inputs and outputs and logic as well) if you show code of `inputhex` module.

Comment: Yes sir, dout and cout have to be wires.  Although dout was not supposed to be an output originally. I just tried that to make it link with the output of inputhex since i was not getting the values. And the input hex is a block RAM generated using IP core and it stores the pixel values of the image. So i do not have the code for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have another issue with the code now. My assignment is as  follows:    wire [16:0] addr_reg [2:0];    assign addr_reg[0]=0; This gives me a value 0000000000000000X instead of 00000000000000000 on addr_reg[0]. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please, add updated your code. I just can say that `X` shows multiple drivers of the net, so it means that you assigned somewhere twice to `addr_reg`

Comment: I figured that the assignment operation (assign addr_reg[0]=0;) was causing the issue. As you mentioned multiple drivers of the net cause the issue. Now the code is working perfectly fine. Thanks for your help Roman  and Greg.